# react-navigation Infinite loop inside componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I Have 2 components, component a and component b

I want to navigate from component a to component b after changing a state.
When i change state, it triggers my componentWillReceiveProps function and i am navigation from there.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const { navigate } = nextProps.navigation;
  navigate('b');
}
```

Now i got in an infinite loop, it starts triggering componentWillReceiveProps again and again instead of navigating

Help needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need compare current this.props and nextProps, you better trigger navigate action in somewhere else.

This link might also help you: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle